# Why does make ignore this rule, and trigger an implicit one instead?

Tags: makefile

I have the following rule in my makefile:

```
$(TESTDIR)/%.test.out:$(TESTDIR)/%.test $(TESTDIR)/%.in
        $< < $(patsubst %.out, %.in, $@) 2>&1 > $@
```

I expect that, when I invoke make

```
make testing/Candidate.test.out
```

(where TESTDIR=testing in the makefile), make should respond with

```
testing/Candidate.test < Candidate.test.in 2>&1 >Candidate.test.out
```

Instead, make responds with

```
cp testing/Candidate.test testing/Candidate.test.out
```

and make -d yields:

```
Considering target file 'testing/Candidate.test.out'.
 File 'testing/Candidate.test.out' does not exist.
 Looking for an implicit rule for 'testing/Candidate.test.out'.
 Trying pattern rule with stem 'Candidate'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite 'testing/Candidate.test'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite 'testing/Candidate.in'.
 Trying pattern rule with stem 'Candidate.test'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite 'testing/Candidate.test'.
 Found an implicit rule for 'testing/Candidate.test.out'.
```

Building with make -r:

```
make -r testing/Candidate.test.out
make: *** No rule to make target 'testing/Candidate.test.out'.  Stop.
```

indicates that make is decidedly not recognizing my rule, but I can't see why not. Clearly make believes $(TESTDIR)=testing, based on the cp output. Clearly it also recognizes testing/Candidate.test.out as a valid target, because it attempts to build it (whereas it fails for testing/blah.test.out).

Is there something obvious I'm missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the targets in the rule (%.in) is incorrect (should be %.test.in).